# Finding the value of $r$ for which the radial function, $P(r)$, has a maximum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, electrons, atomic-physics, hydrogen

In my (university) particle physics course, I am asked to find the values of $r$ for which the function $P(r)$ of a $2s$ Hydrogen electron has its maximum values. 
Here, $r$ denotes the distance in Bohr radii, and $P(r)$ denotes the radial function for a hydrogen-like ion. In the case of a $2s$ hydrogen electron, we have $$P(r)=\sqrt(Z/a) · 2 · (Z·r/a) · \exp(-Z·r/a).$$

$Z=1$ in the case of hydrogen, and $a$ stands for the Bohr radius.
My question is, how do I determine the value of $r$ for the maximum values of $P(r)$?

I know there must be 1 maximum. Do I just differentiate the function with respect to $r$? 
I feel like its a rather simple problem, however I'm stuck on where to start.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: "I know that there's this method I could try, but I can't be bothered to try to see whether it works" isn't a great way to phrase the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the change of variable $x= \frac{Zr}{a}$ you get an equation of the form $K\cdot x \cdot \exp(-x)$ which is a function that admits only one maximum. By differentiating it, you can equal it to zero, then prove it's a maximum by calculating the second derivative. Finally, you should end up with $x=\frac{1}{e}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think differentiation would give the right answer. The differentiation yield a simple answer. If it had however asked the  value of r for which the probability of finding an electron is maximum we would have of course squared the value of the radial probability function and then we would have differentiated.